# Having trouble getting data from mysql database to android app via php with JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm working on an android app that connects to a remote mysql database via a php script.  The script is supposed to query the database, and return the result via JSON data.  I'm trying to use a `userID` and return data related to that user, such as `fistname`, `company` and `position`.

It is returning JSON data, but it's always the same whether I search an existing userID, a userID that doesn't exist or if I leave the `editText` field blank. Basically, this if statement is always resolving to false: `if (!empty($result))` so this is always the result: `$response["message"] = "User not found 2";`

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// check for post data
if (isset($_GET['userID'])) {
    $userid = $_GET['userID'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userid");

    if (!empty($result)) { //<-------This is always resovling to false even when I leave the editText field blank ----------
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $user = array();
            $user["userid"] = $result["userid"];
            $user["firstname"] = $result["firstname"];
            $user["company"] = $result["company"];
            $user["position"] = $result["position"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["user"] = array();

            array_push($response["user"], $user);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "User not found 1";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "User not found 2"; //--------------THIS IS THE RESULT THAT IS ALWAYS RETURNED----------------

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is my android java file:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchByUserID extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Buttons
    private Button mSubmitButton, mBackButton;

    // EditText Field
    EditText enterUserID;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // Variable for holding URL:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.website.com/webservice/searchbyuserid.php";

    //JSON element ids from response of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_by_user_id_layout);

        mSubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mBackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        enterUserID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterUserIdNumber);
        enterUserID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            int keyDel;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                enterUserID.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                            keyDel = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if (keyDel == 0) {
                    int len = enterUserID.getText().length();
                    if(len == 2 || len == 6) {
                        enterUserID.setText(enterUserID.getText() + "-");
                        enterUserID.setSelection(enterUserID.getText().length());
                    }
                } else {
                    keyDel = 0;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.submit:
                new SearchUserId().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.back:
                finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class SearchUserId extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Show progress dialog
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchByUserID.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching User ID...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String userID = enterUserID.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    Log.d("User ID Found!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(SearchByUserID.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("User ID not found.", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(SearchByUserID.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use `mysql_query`? didn't you see the big deprecation messages in the doc?

Comment: what happens if you call the url outside of the android application?

Comment: Doing this sort of project yourself is going to be tedious.  You could cut the problem in half by making a (simple html form) test page for each of your php pages... put in different ids and see what you get back... also you can log what is actually being sent from inside your android app to make sure its not sending the same thing all the time.

Comment: Also you can insert lines like ' echo $result ' in your php to determine whether it contains the expected result or not.

Comment: Your PHP script is right. Problem is that your $_GET['userID'] is empty at everytime. Try to log variable  userID in java class before makeHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the responses...  I'm going to give you suggestions a try when I get home.